# Fast, pythonic way to get all tuples obtained by dropping the elements from a given tuple?

Tags: python, generator

Given a tuple `T` that contains all different integers, I want to get all the tuples that result from dropping individual integers from `T`. I came up with the following code:

```py
def drop(T):
    S = set(T)
    for i in S:
        yield tuple(S.difference({i}))

for t in drop((1,2,3)):
    print(t)
# (2,3)
# (1,3)
# (1,2)
```

I'm not unhappy with this, but I wonder if there is a better/faster way because with large tuples, `difference()` needs to look for the item in the set, but I already know that I'll be removing items sequentially. However, this code is only 2x faster:

```py
def drop(T):
    for i in range(len(T)):
        yield T[:i] + T[i+1:]
```

and in any case, neither scales linearly with the size of `T`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? *No* algorithm will scale linearly with the size of T in O(n), since you want to construct O(n) tuples of size O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looking at it as *"**remove** one item each item"* you can look at it as *"use all **but one**"* and then using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) it becomes straightforward:

```py
from itertools import combinations

T = (1, 2, 3, 4)
for t in combinations(T, len(T)-1):
    print(t)
```

Which gives:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```

<sup>* Assuming the order doesn't really matter</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you're looking for combinations of the elements of T. With itertools.combinations, you can ask for all r-length tuples, in sorted order, without repeated elements. For example :

```
import itertools
T = [1,2,3]
for i in  itertools.combinations(T, len(T) - 1):
   print(i)
```